# How to group by and count rows based on a time interval condition

Tags: datetime, group-by, count, dplyr

Working in R, I have a dataframe with three variables (ID, date-time and blood pressure) where each row is a measurement of a persons blood pressure with an associated measurement time. There are multiple rows per person.

I would like to be able to count the number of rows/measurements in previous 60 minutes of the current row/measurement (per person).

Here are some example data

```
my_df<-data.frame(ID=c("A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C"),
 Measured_DT_TM=as.POSIXct(c("2018-08-01 08:00:00","2018-08-01 08:20:00","2018-08-01 08:30:00","2018-08-01 08:35:00","2018-08-01 11:00:00","2018-08-01 11:30:00","2018-08-01 14:10:00","2018-08-01 15:40:00","2018-08-01 15:00:00","2018-08-01 13:00:00","2018-08-01 13:05:00","2018-08-01 13:30:00","2018-08-01 13:55:00","2018-08-01 14:40:00")),
 blood_pressure=c(115,115,120,130,140,130,120,125,125,150,160,130,130,131))
```

To start I have grouped my data by person, ordered by time. I have created (mutate) a new variable that is the time from the first row/measurement to the current row/measurement (per person) and a variable that is the time from the previous measurment to the current measurement.

```
library(dplyr)
my_df_1<-my_df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  arrange(Measured_DT_TM, .by_group=TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(time_since_first_measure=difftime(Measured_DT_TM, first(Measured_DT_TM), units = c("mins")),
         time_since_prev_measure=difftime(Measured_DT_TM, lag(Measured_DT_TM, n=1), units = c("mins")))

my_df_1
   ID    Measured_DT_TM         bp time_since_first_measure time_since_prev_measure
   <fct> <dttm>              <dbl> <drtn>                   <drtn>                 
 1 A     2018-08-01 08:00:00   115   0 mins                  NA mins               
 2 A     2018-08-01 08:20:00   115  20 mins                  20 mins               
 3 A     2018-08-01 08:30:00   120  30 mins                  10 mins               
 4 A     2018-08-01 08:35:00   130  35 mins                   5 mins               
 5 A     2018-08-01 11:00:00   140 180 mins                 145 mins               
 6 A     2018-08-01 11:30:00   130 210 mins                  30 mins               
 7 B     2018-08-01 14:10:00   120   0 mins                  NA mins               
 8 B     2018-08-01 15:00:00   125  50 mins                  50 mins               
 9 B     2018-08-01 15:40:00   125  90 mins                  40 mins               
10 C     2018-08-01 13:00:00   150   0 mins                  NA mins               
11 C     2018-08-01 13:05:00   160   5 mins                   5 mins               
12 C     2018-08-01 13:30:00   130  30 mins                  25 mins               
13 C     2018-08-01 13:55:00   130  55 mins                  25 mins               
14 C     2018-08-01 14:40:00   131 100 mins                  45 mins
```

I am stuck here how to create/mutate a new variable that counts the number of rows in the previous 60 mins from the current row (per person). I would like to try create the no_'measures_in_prev_60m' variable/column as shown

```
   ID    Measured_DT_TM         bp time_since_first_measure time_since_prev_measure measures_in_prev_60m
   <fct> <dttm>              <dbl> <drtn>                   <drtn>                                 <dbl>
 1 A     2018-08-01 08:00:00   115   0 mins                  NA mins                                  NA
 2 A     2018-08-01 08:20:00   115  20 mins                  20 mins                                   1
 3 A     2018-08-01 08:30:00   120  30 mins                  10 mins                                   2
 4 A     2018-08-01 08:35:00   130  35 mins                   5 mins                                   3
 5 A     2018-08-01 11:00:00   140 180 mins                 145 mins                                   0
 6 A     2018-08-01 11:30:00   130 210 mins                  30 mins                                   1
 7 B     2018-08-01 14:10:00   120   0 mins                  NA mins                                  NA
 8 B     2018-08-01 15:00:00   125  50 mins                  50 mins                                   1
 9 B     2018-08-01 15:40:00   125  90 mins                  40 mins                                   1
10 C     2018-08-01 13:00:00   150   0 mins                  NA mins                                  NA
11 C     2018-08-01 13:05:00   160   5 mins                   5 mins                                   1
12 C     2018-08-01 13:30:00   130  30 mins                  25 mins                                   2
13 C     2018-08-01 13:55:00   130  55 mins                  25 mins                                   3
14 C     2018-08-01 14:40:00   131 100 mins                  45 mins                                   1
```

Can anyone offer advice/help?
Thanks

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please accept it and vote it up! Feel free to ask for clarification if needed. I ended up not using "time_since_prev_measure" because it's only relative to one previous and so it would not capture more than 1 easily.

Comment: Thank you, for the answer - really helpful. It's a different solution to the way I was thinking but great to learn different approaches. I'm not very familiar with pmap so I'm going to look that up to make sure I fully understand. Thanks

Comment: Another point to make is that this is just an example scenario. I have a very large dataset (over 20 million rows) to work on so any advice on coding that will run efficiently on big data would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you know base R, map/pmap are similar to lapply/mapply, which is R's way of doing loops. When map and/or pmap are done in a data frame / tibble, it's applying a function to every row. Normally, within mutate, we use vectorized functions and they already handle inputs/outputs for each row, but in this case, we are building our own thing that compares a column of vectors with a column of numbers.

Comment: Not sure how it'll work on 20M rows - please let me know how it goes!

Comment: here are some good articles about how I used pmap https://www.google.com/search?q=mutate+vectorized+function+purrr&oq=mutate+vectorized+function+purrr&aqs=chrome..69i57j33.5480j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: and the rstudio cheat sheets are always helpful https://www.rstudio.com/resources/cheatsheets/#purrr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good case to use list-columns, part of the `tidyverse` and `purrr` package.

I put all the durations for each ID into each line with `mutate(y = list(x))`, which creates a list-column. Then I create the criteria for each row (the cutoff). Then I test each duration if it qualifies (within the previous 60 min), using `pmap` which operates on each row and takes in multiple inputs (i.e. the set of durations and the cutoffs). At the same time, for each row, I add up the elements that qualify.

```r
library(tidyverse, quietly = TRUE)
#> Warning: package 'tidyverse' was built under R version 3.5.3
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 3.5.3
#> Warning: package 'tibble' was built under R version 3.5.3
#> Warning: package 'tidyr' was built under R version 3.5.3
#> Warning: package 'readr' was built under R version 3.5.2
#> Warning: package 'purrr' was built under R version 3.5.3
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 3.5.3
#> Warning: package 'stringr' was built under R version 3.5.2
#> Warning: package 'forcats' was built under R version 3.5.2

my_df<-data.frame(ID=c("A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C"),
                  Measured_DT_TM=as.POSIXct(c("2018-08-01 08:00:00","2018-08-01 08:20:00","2018-08-01 08:30:00","2018-08-01 08:35:00","2018-08-01 11:00:00","2018-08-01 11:30:00","2018-08-01 14:10:00","2018-08-01 15:40:00","2018-08-01 15:00:00","2018-08-01 13:00:00","2018-08-01 13:05:00","2018-08-01 13:30:00","2018-08-01 13:55:00","2018-08-01 14:40:00")),
                  blood_pressure=c(115,115,120,130,140,130,120,125,125,150,160,130,130,131)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  arrange(Measured_DT_TM, .by_group=TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(time_since_first_measure=difftime(Measured_DT_TM, first(Measured_DT_TM), units = c("mins")),
         time_since_prev_measure=difftime(Measured_DT_TM, lag(Measured_DT_TM, n=1), units = c("mins")))

# steps broken out for readability
my_df %>% 
  mutate(all_measures_by_ID = list(time_since_first_measure),
         cutoff_60 = time_since_first_measure - 60, 
         check_for_measures_within_prev_60m = pmap(list(all_measures_by_ID, time_since_first_measure, cutoff_60), ~(..1 < ..2 & ..1 >= ..3)),
         no_measures_in_prev_60m = map(check_for_measures_within_prev_60m, sum)) %>%
  View()

# results in one line and no extra columns
my_df %>% 
  mutate(no_measures_in_prev_60m = pmap(list(list(time_since_first_measure), time_since_first_measure, time_since_first_measure - 60), 
                                        ~sum(..1 < ..2 & ..1 >= ..3))) %>%
  unnest(no_measures_in_prev_60m) %>%
  select(no_measures_in_prev_60m, everything())
#> # A tibble: 14 x 6
#> # Groups:   ID [3]
#>    no_measures_in_~ ID    Measured_DT_TM      blood_pressure
#>               <int> <fct> <dttm>                       <dbl>
#>  1                0 A     2018-08-01 08:00:00            115
#>  2                1 A     2018-08-01 08:20:00            115
#>  3                2 A     2018-08-01 08:30:00            120
#>  4                3 A     2018-08-01 08:35:00            130
#>  5                0 A     2018-08-01 11:00:00            140
#>  6                1 A     2018-08-01 11:30:00            130
#>  7                0 B     2018-08-01 14:10:00            120
#>  8                1 B     2018-08-01 15:00:00            125
#>  9                1 B     2018-08-01 15:40:00            125
#> 10                0 C     2018-08-01 13:00:00            150
#> 11                1 C     2018-08-01 13:05:00            160
#> 12                2 C     2018-08-01 13:30:00            130
#> 13                3 C     2018-08-01 13:55:00            130
#> 14                1 C     2018-08-01 14:40:00            131
#> # ... with 2 more variables: time_since_first_measure <drtn>,
#> #   time_since_prev_measure <drtn>
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>